# Cannot set session ID after the session has started at MockArraySessionStorage.php:127

Tags: symfony, testing, symfony-2.8

I want to test a form via functional tests.
After filling in the form et then submit , the following error message was displayed :

**[2020-06-11 17:45:32] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "Cannot set session ID after the session has started." at /var/www/renault-del/del/src/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/MockArraySessionStorage.php line 127 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Cannot set session ID after the session has started. at /var/www/renault-del/del/src/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/MockArraySessionStorage.php:127)"} []**

For information , this is my script that i used to sumit a form :

```
class CmsBlockControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{


    /** @var Client */
    private $client;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->client = static::createClient();


    }



    public function testNewAction(): void
    {

        $crawler = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            $this->generateRoute('delbackoffice_cms_block_new') // my own function to generate a route
        );


        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Enregistrer')
            ->form([
                'block[title]' => 'title',
                'block[identifier]' => 'identifier',
                'block[content]' => 'content']);

         $this->client->submit($form);

    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->client = null;
        $this->tokenStorage = null;
        $this->globalVariables = null;
    }
}
```

And thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while, I found the solution by calling **disableReboot** on test.client.class in the following link :  [Solution here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13450)

So, i added  **$this->client->disableReboot();** after client creation. so it worked :)